# Cannot import FactorAnalyzer from module factor-analyzer-0.2.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed the module factor-analyzer-0.2.2 but cannot import the function. My code is `from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer`. I'm getting an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'factor_analyzer'`.
I'm using Python 3.6 and Jupyter notebook. Do you know why this does not work? 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Mac (python3). I launch Spyder 3.3.3 via Anaconda. 
In response to the following code:

```
from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer
```

I received the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'factor_analyzer'
```

So, I opened Terminal (equivalent of Command Prompt on windows) and typed:

```
pip install factor_analyzer
```

Then, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Use the anaconda prompt to run the `pip install factor-analyzer` rather than termainal or powershell. I had the same problem and doing that solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run the import command on your Python Shell and let us know if you are able to import it successfully?

Comment: I checked this in Python Shell. I had the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'factor_analyzer'`. Also I checked the list of modules in Python Shell by `help('modules')` and the list of modules does not have `factor_analyzer`. I installed this module directly from Jupyter and it says the module is installed in \anaconda2\lib\site-packages

Comment: I see the problem now. I have currently installed both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6. This code I run in Python 3 but the package is installed in Anaconda2. How can I solve this issue without changing Python 3 to 2?

Comment: To install the package in Python 3 type "pip3 install factor_analyzer" 

However, you still won't be able to use it in Anaconda as it is in Python 2. 

The optimal solution would be to install Python3 shell in Anaconda. So while creating a notebook you'll have an option to use either Python 2  or Python3

To install Python 3 kernel in Anaconda 2, Please refer this documentation https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html

Comment: I checked on this and I have both kernels installed (Python 2 and Python 3).